# Google Colab - Spotipy not redirecting me to the specified redirect_uri

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, spotify, spotipy

I want to experiment with the Spotify API using the Spotipy python package.

So to start, in my Spotify Developer app,
**I have set the redirect_uri to https://example.com/callback/**

This is the code I am trying to run on a Google Colab notebook

```
import pandas as pd
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

spotify_details = {
    'client_id' : '<hidden>',
    'client_secret':'<hidden>',
    'redirect_uri':'https://example.com/callback/'}

scope = "user-library-read user-follow-read user-top-read playlist-read-private" 

sp = spotipy.Spotify(
        auth_manager=spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(
          client_id=spotify_details['client_id'],
          client_secret=spotify_details['client_secret'],
          redirect_uri=spotify_details['redirect_uri'],    
          scope=scope))

results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
for idx, item in enumerate(results['items']):
    track = item['track']
    print(idx, track['artists'][0]['name'], " – ", track['name'])
```

This is what I see as the output:

[image]

**But my browser does not redirect me to any URL for me to receive an auth token**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colab is a browserless environment, so as suggested [in the FAQ](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-obtain-authorization-in-a-headlessbrowserless-environment) you should add the parameter

```py
open_browser=False
```

when you instantiate your spotipy.SpotifyOAuth object:

```py
sp = spotipy.Spotify(
        auth_manager=spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(
          client_id=spotify_details['client_id'],
          client_secret=spotify_details['client_secret'],
          redirect_uri=spotify_details['redirect_uri'],    
          scope=scope, open_browser=False))
```

In this way, the notebook will print out the URL that you can open manually:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, rob_med. This works perfectly. A classic mistake on my part of searching everywhere except the sites own FAQ.

Comment: Just tested this solution. Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In case any one is wondering what is the URL we need to follow is

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<encoded_redirect_uri>&response_type=code
```

once the request is complete it will be redirected to (if your redirect_uri is https://example.com/callback/)

```
https://example.com/callback/?code=<code_will_be_present_here>
```

Use the above url in the collab input box